# In a piano score, what is the meaning of a V with a dot in it

Tags: notation

In a beginners piano scorebook, under the last cord there is a V with a dot in it. I searched but can't find what it could mean. In case that matters, it's a French book.

[image: V with dot in final chord]

There is no other place in the score where I can find this symbol. What should I do with it or how to play this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's called a "staccato duro", and as the other answer correctly wrote, it's a marked staccato, i.e. shorter than the note duration and with force.

For future reference: all musical symbols and their explanations can be found on [dolmetsch](https://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm)

Answer (score 10):

It's a combination of the wedge (marcato) and the dot (staccato). The note is to be played shorter than normal (like a staccato) but forcefully (like with the wedge.) I didn't find a specific name for the symbol.

Answer (score 7):

It could also be a short fermata. It is a lesser-known mark signifying that a note is to be played longer than the indicated duration, but only slightly longer.

See [this page](http://donrathjr.com/fermata-music-theory/) for an explanation.

[image: fermata types]

Comment: Gardner Read's "Music Notation" (1979), p. 108, calls the blue and green versions a modern innovation.  (So it's not found in music before 1945.)  The traditional notation would be to add a *lunga* or a *poco* to the traditional fermata.

Comment: If it were any sort of fermata, it would be above the staff, not below the note.

Comment: @phoog - usually, but not always.

Answer (score 3):

Called 'martellato', it's to make sure the note(s) is/are played strongly, hammered. Not necessarily staccato as such. Used more often in violin music - a strong downbow from the frog - but also piano and vox.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen other than the crescent. I have seen (and used) fermatas over different length notes (quarter, half, whole, tied wholes) to indicate the length of the fermata. The angular one is a right angle which differs from the dotted wedge in having a bigger angle. I probably would have read the green version as a staccato down-bow.

Comment: @ttw did you mean to comment on my answer rather than Tim's?